# Why scope annotations have RUNTIME retention in Dagger 2?

Tags: dagger-2

Dagger 2 has compile-time validation, so why do the scope annotations have `RUNTIME` retention? Why are they needed at runtime?

Comment: Adding to the above, JSR 330 for sure did not have dagger in mind, and there are also runtime dependency injection frameworks that *would* need them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Though I don't know for sure, I'd guess that Scopes necessarily have runtime retention because [JSR 330's `@Scope`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Scope.html) requires scopes to have runtime retention. ([`@Qualifier`](http://javax-inject.github.io/javax-inject/api/javax/inject/Qualifier.html) has the same restriction.) Both Dagger 1 and Dagger 2 advertise JSR-330 compatibility, and (as [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1837367/david-medenjak) mentions in the comments) there are plenty of runtime dependency injection solutions that would absolutely require runtime-retained scope annotations.

For Dagger in particular, I can't imagine why they'd actually be read at runtime either, though I suppose some external libraries could make use of the annotation.

---

### Edit from comments + Android multidex caveat

This is not necessarily a problem, legacy or otherwise: Many DI systems configure at runtime and require the annotation. Dagger is notable in that it doesn't, but the spec was not written in a way that allows for runtime retention to be optional. This frees app developers to replace Dagger with a different JSR330 framework like Guice or Spring, and it frees library developers to make DI-compatible tools or frameworks agnostic to whether they are compile-time-configured or runtime-configured. That spec clarity (i.e. without implementation options) and flexibility (compile time or runtime) seems worth the cost of unnecessary annotation retention and the cost of learning.

**However, this *can* be a problem in large Android apps** because [Android keeps runtime-annotated classes in the main dex by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41097666/1426891); older versions of Android fail to load runtime annotations if the annotated class is in a secondary dex. See [this bug](http://b.android.com/78144) linked from the [`keepRuntimeAnnotatedClasses` docs](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DexOptions.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DexOptions:keepRuntimeAnnotatedClasses) for details. Though you could consider this a Dagger problem because of Dagger's applicability to large Android apps, it's more of a bug with Android annotation handling, for which Dagger would need to diverge from the JSR-330 spec in order to handle itself.

Comment: So this is like legacy problem? It does not simplify learning Dagger 2 usage.

Comment: Thanks, you helped a lot.