# Still "too many classes" with multidex enabled. Does multidex have a (bigger) limit also?

Tags: android, android-multidex

So it is already known that the solution to this error:

```
com.android.dex.DexException: Too many classes in --main-dex-list, main dex capacity exceeded
```

Is to enable multidex support. I have done so, as well as applying proguard shrinking, but still get that error. Is there also a limit for multidex (presumably much higher than 64k)?

I am using several huge libraries, but it'd be nice to know the answer to this before somehow re-engineering everything to use fewer libraries. (I'm porting a desktop app to Android.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Too many classes in --main-dex-list, main dex capacity exceeded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32721083/too-many-classes-in-main-dex-list-main-dex-capacity-exceeded)

Answer (score 1):

The solution to *that* particular error message is *not* to enable multi-dex support. The error appears when multi-dex support *is* enabled, but the build system determined that too many methods need to be added to the main dex file for your app to work.

Depending on your Android Gradle plugin version you might be affected by [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=206131) which causes too many methods to be included in the main dex file. The solution is to upgrade to Android Gradle plugin 2.2 or newer, and build tools 24 or newer.

If that does not solve the problem, you might indeed have to many (transitive) method dependencies in your main activities `onCreate()` code.